# Can i set scrollview below header view programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Header which is in relative layout. Can i set scroll view below this headerrelative layout PROGRAMATICALLY?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can set scroll view below this headerrelative layout PROGRAMATICALLY.

e.g

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) scrollView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.header_relative_id);
scrollView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: @arol_8021- I tried with creating scroll view dynamically and sets layoutparams for that scroll but its depreciated, and add my view in that scroll view, now i want that scroll view below my header.